# linear bounded functional on hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Hi Guys can some one help with this question?

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and F a linear bounded functional in $\mathcal{H}^∗$
such that $F \neq 0$. Prove that dim(kerF)$^{\perp} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem on homomorphisms says:

$$ \dim \mathcal H/ker F = \dim F(\mathcal H)=1.$$

Together with $ \mathcal H= ker F \oplus (ker F)^{\perp}$ the result follows.

Comment: can you explain it more please? with more details

Comment: @Mathgamer If you don't understand this, you should take a step back. It is basic linear algebra.

Comment: I do understand this . but is this enough as an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

By Riesz representation theorem, there is $u\in H$ such that $F(v) = \langle v, u\rangle $ for all $v\in H$.
Then $\ker F = span(u)^\perp$ and $(\ker F)^\perp = span(u)^{\perp\perp} = span(u)$, since $span(u)$ is finite-dimensional hence closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take the field as $\mathbb{R}$ for example. Check the proof of Riesz Representation theorem, you'll see we constructed $a$ such that $f(x) = <x,a> $ where $a \in Ker(f)^{\perp}$. The uniqueness of Riesz Representation theorem implies $Ker(f)^{\perp}$ must be 1-dimensional (otherwise at least 2 linearly independent vectors after rescaling can both represent $f$ as an inner product, which is a contradiction).